# Advice me in out of range problem of my cone creator

Tags: vba, autocad

I've run this code and click draw I've found a out of range problem And Debugger give me a highlight to this line `Set coneobject = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddCone(conecenter, coneradius, coneheight)`

But this is no mistake for me 
Can you suggest me ,please ?

[image]

```
 Private Sub cmd_draw_Click()
        UserForm1.Hide
        Dim coneangle As Double

        Select Case comboboxangle.Text
            Case 0
                coneangle = 15
            Case 1
                coneangle = 30
            Case 2
                coneangle = 45
            Case 3
                coneangle = 60
        End Select
        Drawcone coneangle
        UserForm1.show

    End Sub

    Public Sub Drawcone(coneangle As Double)
        Dim coneobject As Acad3DSolid
        Dim conecenter As Variant
        Dim coneheight As Double
        'Dim coneangle As Double
        Dim coneradius As Double
        coneheight = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text

        With ThisDrawing.Utility
            conecenter = .GetPoint(, vbCr & "select position for Top of cone:")
        End With

        conecenter(2) = conecenter(2) - coneheight / 2#
        coneradius = coneheight * Tan(coneangle)

        'Set coneobject = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddCone(conecenter, coneradius, coneheight)
        Set coneobject = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddCone(conecenter, coneradius, coneheight)
        coneobject.Update
        ThisDrawing.ChangeViewDirection

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmd_finish_Click()
        Unload Me

    End Sub

    ''Private Sub cmd_pickpoint_Click()
        ''UserForm1.Hide
        ''Dim conecenter As Variant
        'With ThisDrawing.Utility
            'conecenter = .GetPoint(, vbCr & "select position for Top of cone:")
        'End With
        'UserForm1.show

    'End Sub


    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

        With comboboxangle
            .AddItem "15"
            .AddItem "30"
            .AddItem "45"
            .AddItem "60"
            .Text = "Empty"
        End With


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible issue is your use of the [`tan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/tan-function) function: trigonomonetric functions such `tan` operate using angular values expressed in **radians**, not degrees.

As such, you will need to change:

```vb
coneradius = coneheight * Tan(coneangle)
```

to:

```vb
coneradius = coneheight * Tan(pi * (coneangle / 180#))
```

Using degrees will not cause the function to error (since you are still supplying a numerical value), but the value will be interpreted in radians and so will yield unexpected results (e.g. 15 degrees will be interpreted as 15 radians = 139.4 degrees).

Comment: But the debug give me highlight to `coneheight` in this line (`Set coneobject = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddCone(conecenter, coneradius, coneheight)`)

Comment: @T.Horizon Have you verified that the height you are supplying to the `addcone` method is positive & non-zero?

Comment: can you recheck method that I've import height value.
`coneheight = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text`
any mistake for this line ? 
(P.S : I'm very beginner for this)

Comment: @T.Horizon I think it should be either `coneheight = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value` or `coneheight = UserForm1.TextBox1`; or to force the type conversion: `coneheight = CDbl(UserForm1.TextBox1)`

Comment: now, I've checked the variant's value by drag in that value and coneradius = 0, coneheight = 20 (value I filled)
,Is this unusual ?

Comment: @T.Horizon It depends whether you are checking the value before the `coneradius` is defined. It will be `0` until the expression `coneradius = coneheight * Tan(pi * (coneangle / 180#))` is evaluated to define it.

Comment: Sorry for late  reply ,I've checked the value of variant when I run it.In the select case that I want to set the coneangle's value it told me its value was 0 until set value for variable.

Hope you still there ,I'm so sorry for late reply

Comment: @T.Horizon I would suggest the following: just before this line: `Set coneobject = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddCone(conecenter, coneradius, coneheight)`, add the following line: `debug.print conecenter : debug.print coneradius : debug.print coneheight` This will indicate the values being supplied to the `addcone` method.